# Implementing mobile scrolling on asp.net mvc project

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to diagnose a problem that I am having when scrolling on mobile devices. I don't know where to look, but I think it may be the scripts / css that I am using in my project. The problem that is happening is that on mobile, scrolling acts as it would on the desktop. I don't get a view that "slides" as I scroll up or down.

My bundle config

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.UseCdn = true;

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/amplify").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/amplify.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

        // Set EnableOptimizations to false for debugging. For more information,
        // visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
}
```

My _Layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Learn ASP.NET MVC</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>    
    <script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")    
</head>
<body>
    <!--- --->

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/amplify")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Would there be any reason why it doesn't load properly? This is a mostly fresh-out-of-the-box asp.net mvc project.

Comment: What do you mean you don't get a view that slides? Perhaps screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, when scrolling on an iPod, (or any mobile device), the view does not slide. By default in iOS applications, you have the nice "swipe" feature. The speed of your swipe carries momentum and you see things slide across the screen. In the music app in iOS, when you swipe up or down, your view scrolls - it's this effect that's missing here

Comment: So what happens when you try to scroll right now? It doesn't have any momentum? By the way, what you described is commonly referred to as "momentum scrolling"

Comment: It does not have momentum. When the project was made, it did. Now it's gone when you browse here: http://learnaspnetmvc.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was having this style on my html and body. Removing this fixed all of the problems.

```
html, body {overflow-x:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 1):

From  [CSS Tricks "Momentum Scrolling on iOS Overflow Elements"](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/)

> Web pages on iOS by default have a "momentum" style scrolling where a
>   flick of the finger sends the web page scrolling and it keeps going
>   until eventually slowing down and stopping as if friction is slowing
>   it down. Like if you were to push a hockey puck across the ice or
>   something. You might think that any element with scrolling would have
>   this behavior as well, but it doesn't. You can add it back with a
>   special property.

```
.module {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;

  overflow-y: scroll; /* has to be scroll, not auto */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Plenty of comments at the above link may also be helpful.